# How to animate an element where the trigger is a data change on the property you want to animate

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, resize

I want to animate my WPF window. It's set to size to content, so when the content changes, the window changes size. I don't want it to snap to a new size though, when it determines it needs a new size I want it to lerp between the old and new value with an animation.

How do I set this up?

EDIT:
I am using SizeToContent=WidthAndHeight" as a parameter for my window, and want to animate when it automatically sizes to different content being shown.

Comment: Just don't use SizeToContent. Probably use a top/left-aligned ContentControl. Whenever you've assigned it a new Content, get its layout done and query its current size. Then animate the Window size accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You may override the `OnPropertyChanged` method and start an animation of any property you like.

For example, the Width property:

```
private DoubleAnimation widthAnimation;

protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Property == WidthProperty &&
        !double.IsNaN((double)e.OldValue) &&
        widthAnimation == null)
    {
        widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            From = (double)e.OldValue,
            To = (double)e.NewValue
        };

        widthAnimation.Completed += (s, a) =>
        {
            widthAnimation = null;
            BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, null);
        };

        BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, widthAnimation);
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I will be needing, thanks. However, I can't get the animation to play right now. Its hitting the code, but the width and height are snapping to their desired size and ignoring the animation completely. I have the following parameters in xaml for the window which may well be important / the reason this isn't working: `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Height="Auto" MinHeight="50" Width="Auto" MinWidth="50" ResizeMode="NoResize"`

Comment: Not sure if it works with SizeToContent. I've only tested to set a specific Width.